# Taking inputs in HTML and using javascript to print output (geometric calculator)?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am (obviously) very new to JS/HTML and coding in general. I am trying to create a geometric calculator that takes a radius in a text box, and then an input in a radius bubble and depending on the radius will put the entered radius into a particular formula and print out the result. It will take the radius, and the radio bubble selection and either print out the circle circumference, circle area, sphere surface area or sphere volume. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
    <h1>Geometric Calculator Application</h1>
    <p>This application will take input the radius of a circle and the required measure for the following choices: Circle circumference, Circle area, Sphere surface area, and Sphere volume. After circle radius is inserted, select action you want to perform and press submit. 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Casio_calculator_JS-20WK_in_201901_002.jpg/1200px-Casio_calculator_JS-20WK_in_201901_002.jpg" alt="Calculator Picture" width="30%" height="30%" style="float:right" style="clear:right">       
    <br>    
    <br>
    </p>
        <label for="radius">Radius</label>
        <input type="text" id="radius" name="radius" onclick="solve()"/><br>
        <br>
        <label for="cc">Circle Circumference</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="cc" value="cc" onclick="solve()"/><br>
        
        <label for="ca">Circle Area</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="ca" value="ca" onclick="solve()"/><br>
        
        <label for="ssa">Sphere Surface Area</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="ssa" value="ssa" onclick="solve()"/><br>
        
        <label for="sv">Sphere Volume</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="sv" value="sv" onclick="solve()"/><br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="solve()"/>
            
            <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        function solve() { 
            var ele = document.getElementsByName('radius'); 
            if valueOf(radio)="cc":
                return (2*3.14*"radius")
            if valueOf(radio)="ca":
                return (3.14*"radius"**2)
            if valueOf(radio)="ssa":
                return (4*3.14*"radius"**2)
            if valueOf(radio)="sv":
                return ((4/3)*3.14*"radius"**3)     
            } 
        }  
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, im sure this is easy for some people out there but incredibly tough for me.

Comment: `if valueOf(radio)="cc":` There are so many things wrong with this - consider looking into a tutorial on basic JS syntax and element selecting, you will learn much more doing that first IMO

Comment: I know that - I only know Python and am doing an online practice. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have made a few changes to your code. Do ask if you face any other issues/doubts:

1. The **onclick()** event needs to be fired only once, when the user presses the submit button. So no need to specify it for every radio button. Doesn't make any sense.
2. Since there's just one variable that your function needs, i.e. the radius, so it's better to use document.getElementById(someId), rather than document.getElementsByName(someName). The first one returns just one HTML element corresponding to the specified "id". The second one returns an array of elements having that "name", which you will have to iterate using a loop to access the first element indexed as 0 since you won't have any other elements with the name 'radius' (in your case). In your case, you have just one element "radius", so better to access it through the "id".
3. To access the clicked radio element, you check whether the value of 'clicked' attribute for that particular radio button is 'true' or 'false', while iterating through the array of radio buttons. Here, we use document.getElementsByName(someName) since radio buttons belonging to the same group are identified through their name.

Feel free to ask any other doubts! Here's the working modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
    <h1>Geometric Calculator Application</h1>
    <p>This application will take input the radius of a circle and the required measure for the following choices: Circle circumference, Circle area, Sphere surface area, and Sphere volume. After circle radius is inserted, select action you want to perform and press submit. 
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Casio_calculator_JS-20WK_in_201901_002.jpg/1200px-Casio_calculator_JS-20WK_in_201901_002.jpg" alt="Calculator Picture" width="30%" height="30%" style="float:right" style="clear:right">       
    <br>    
    <br>
    </p>
        <label for="radius">Radius</label>
        <input type="text" id="radius" name="radius"/><br>
        <br>
        <label for="cc">Circle Circumference</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="cc" value="cc"/><br>
        
        <label for="ca">Circle Area</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="ca" value="ca"/><br>
        
        <label for="ssa">Sphere Surface Area</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="ssa" value="ssa"/><br>
        
        <label for="sv">Sphere Volume</label>
        <input type="radio" name="calc" id="sv" value="sv"/><br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="solve()"/>
           
            
        <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        function solve() { 
            let radius = document.getElementById('radius').value; //entered radius
            
            let ele = document.getElementsByName('calc'); //array of radio buttons with name 'calc'
            
            let resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');//accessing result div
            
            let answer;
            
            for(let i=0; i<ele.length; i++) {//iterating through all the radio buttons
                if(ele[i].checked) { //checking if this radio button was selected by user
                    let radioVal =  ele[i].value; //value of selected radio button
                    
                    if(radioVal == "cc")
                        answer = 2*3.14*radius;
                        
                    if(radioVal == "ca")
                        answer = 3.14*radius*radius;
                    
                    if(radioVal == "ssa")
                        answer = 4*3.14*radius*2;
                        
                    if(radioVal == "sv")
                        answer = (4/3)*3.14*radius*3;
                }
            }
            
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "Result: " + answer;
        }  
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```